# Products are not showing in frontend in Magento 2.4.1

Tags: elasticsearch, magento2.4.0

I have installed 3 fresh magento 2.4.0 in server with elasticsearch as a separate container. I have created products in all 3 magento websites. But products are not showing up in frontend. Products are showing only after reindexing. Can anyone please help me on this issue?

Comment: Did you resolve your issue?

Comment: Already we have configured the cron job and set the indexing mode as well. But not working properly.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you have enabled magento cronjobs on your server. You can enable it by this command

```
php bin/magento cron:install
```

If cronjobs are already installed, then you can set your indexing mode for **"Update by Schedule"** to **"Update on Save"**

**"Update on Save"** change could effect the admin product add performance, but it will show the products instantly after adding.